# What do I have to do to make a constraint for my subview?

Tags: ios, uitouch, restriction, touchesbegan, touchesmoved

I dont want the user to be able to slide an item more than 2/3 way up the screen.

Do I alter touchesBegan or touchesMoved? if so, how?

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    returnLocation = [touch locationInView:self.superview];
    returnLocation.x += self.frame.size.width/2-startlocation.x;
    returnLocation.y += self.frame.size.width/2-startlocation.y;
}
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch* touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentLocation = [touch locationInView:self.superview];
    self.center = currentLocation;
```